# Verify if data was returned from preferred region in cosmos

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

So I have setup my cosmos in 2 regions (say West US and South Central US). I also have my app services running in these two region and connecting to cosmos. For app services running in each region I have configured my preferred region list. So for app service running WUS region, preferred list is in order [WUS, SCUS] and for app service running SCUS region, preferred list is in order [SCUS, WUS].

I want to verify if this configuration is working and my data was returned from cosmos region in order as i have mentioned. For example if accessed from WUS app service, verify if region chooses to execute the query was WUS and vice versa.

Is there any way to verify this?

**NOTE** : I am using **spring-data-cosmosdb-2.1.2** to connect to cosmos.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just dump the Diagnostics returned in the response object and look for the FQDN to the endpoint. It will have a regional subdomain pre-pended to the URI.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can get that information from Response in code but you can make use of Cosmos Metrics in Azure portal.There you can filter the metrics on Region.
So, Attempt a request through App from region 1 and then verify in portal that expected Cosmos region served it. Test in same way for region 2.